# Read integers into linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

this is for a project for class. (C language)

I am having trouble with the `first function` that I'll need to implement. It's a load function where I take an input filename, open up a file given by user at runtime, and read it into a linked list format from a file with an integer on each line.

I am stuck with `how to create the linked list` so that they are all actually linked, without the `same node in the list being overwritten each time`.

This is what I have so far, which I know is incorrect.

```
#include"sortingheaders.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

///////////////////////////////
Node* List_Create(Node * ln)
{
  if(ln==NULL)
    { 
   ln = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      ln->value = 0;
      ln->next = NULL;
    }
  return ln;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Node* Load_File(char *Filename)
{
  //Open file
  FILE* fptr = fopen(Filename, "r");
  Node* ln=NULL;
  Node* temp=NULL;
  long int *x = 0;
//Validity Check, return 0 if unsuccesful
  if(fptr ==NULL)
    {printf("File didnt open!"); return 0;}
 ln= List_Create(ln);
  while(!feof(fptr))
    {
      fscanf(fptr,"%li",x);
      ln->value = *x;
      ln->next = List_Create(temp);
      return(ln);
    }
```

Comment: you want `long int x` and `ln->value = x`, at least.

Comment: and you're returning from inside the loop, and you're not checking that the fscanf worked.

Comment: Just add `temp=NULL` into the while loop before calling List_Create(), so nodes won't overlap. And why you put return() in loop?

Comment: I didnt put that inside the loop like that, transferring my over the format got slightly messed up, and someone edited it to that way and it was approved. So al I need to do is make temp=null so that it is initialized?? Thanks for the lips about long int x and about checking my fscanf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first of the while loop add this.

```
    temp = NULL;
```